# What's the issue with this code?

Tags: python

This is my part of the code:

```
import functions
def assign_tasks(operators, requests, current_time):
    sort_requests(requests)
    print(requests)
```

The error is:

```
NameError: name 'sort_requests' is not defined
```

The function module has the following functions:

```
def sort_requests(requests):
   requests.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(3),reverse=True)
   return requests 
def sort_operators_hours(operators):
   operators.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(4))
   return operators
```

Comment: You have to use the function calling the module name first: `functions.sort_request(requests)` or change your import line: `from functions import sort_requests`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `from functions import sort_requests` or replace `sort_requests(requests)` by `functions.sort_requests(requests)`

Answer (score 0):

First :  Check your import statement. 
Is it function or functions.IT should be the name of your python file name.

Second  : your function sort_requests has a return statement. U need to store the returned output.Try this

```
import functions
def assign_tasks(operators, requests, current_time):
    requests = sort_requests(requests)
    print(requests)
```